# Different ways to initialize variables

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

There are different ways to initialize a variable in c++.
`int z(3)` is same as int `z=3`.
Is

```
int z;
z(3);
```

same as

```
int z;
z=3;
```

?

Comment: For ints it does the exact same thing (Assuming you meant `int z(3)` ). For more complex types read about constructors, `operator=` and other fun things.

Comment: I think your second snippet was meant to be `int z(3)` which is equivalent.

Comment: Just to emphasize - if you're serious about learning C++ you should definitely learn about how assignment works, how construction works and the difference in some cases.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
int z;
z = 3;
```

Or just:

```
int z = 3;
```

Or:

```
int z(3);
```

Or:

```
int z = int(3);
```

Comment: With C++11, you can also use `int z={3}` or `int z{3}`

Comment: The last example of the answer should be `auto z = int(3);`, since the type is stated explicitly at the right side. However, especially for non-primitive types, [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) as shown in the second example by @trm is the most flexible variant (especially when refactoring).

Comment: int z {}; will initialize variable z to 0. that's the beauty of C++ 11. Where int z; will be initialized with garbage value

Answer (score 4):

`z(3);` by itself is invalid syntax. The only way it would be valid is if you had a function called `z`, that you passed in the integer 3. But even that wouldn't necessarily set the local variable `z` to 3.

`int z(3);` will compile in C++ only (not C).

`int z;`
`z=3;`

is valid syntax and will set `z` equal to 3.

Both `int z(3)` and `int z; z=3;` are the same in this case.

Answer (score 3):

No `z(3);` is calling a function called `z` with argument `3`

If you want to initialize using that syntax you need to do that in the declaration

```
int z(3):
```

You can however initialize z like this

```
int z{3};
```

This is the recommended way to initialize variables since C++11

The advantage with syntax is that it gives an error when there is a narrowing conversion i.e. if it is not guaranteed that the value will fit into the target variable you get a compile error. The syntax can be used on any object.

Reference: Item 7, Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers

Answer (score 0):

No, the first option is incorrect: most vexing parse. The compiler thinks that `z` is a function. However these too are basically exactly the same:

```
int z(3);
int z = 3;
```

Note that they are the same in this case, but on objects, the first calls a matching constructor while the second requires an overload of copy assignment operator (`=`)

Comment: `int z(3)` doesn't compile in C

Comment: Ah in C it doesn't :).. that's my problem

Comment: @staticx it's quite common syntax in C++, especially for more complex types - for example it's very common to see `std::vector<MyType> vec(30)` and such. awesomeyi, I would appreciate it if you elaborate on the fact they're _not_ always the same but are the same _in this case_.

Answer (score 0):

As AndersK suggested, the best way to initialize variables in C++ is using {}. Because it ensures type safety, let's talk more about it.

### Type Safety

Every object in C++ is used according to its type and an object needs to be initialized before its use.

#### Safe Initialization: {}

The compiler protects from information loss during type conversion. For example,
`int a{7};` The initialization is OK
`int b{7.5}` Compiler shows ERROR because of information loss.

#### Unsafe Initialization: = or ()

The compiler doesn't protect from information loss during type conversion.
`int a = 7` The initialization is OK
`int a = 7.5` The initialization is OK, but information loss occurs. The actual value of a will become 7.0
`int c(7)` The initialization is OK
`int c(7.5)` The initialization is OK, but information loss occurs. The actual value of a will become 7.0