# Different ways of initializing a C++ variable

Tags: c++

I know that when you declare variables in a class, they should be initialized in the constructors initialization list. If I did not want to do that and initialize it outside of the constructor, would the syntax Object obj = Object(parameter) be valid? I don't really understand the mechanic behind initializing it that way.

Comment: by outside the constructor, you mean in a different method?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543875/different-ways-to-initialize-variables

Comment: Neither of those "related" questions have anything to do with class members.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm using Object's copy constructor to achieve that. Are they any unwanted side effects to this method?

Answer (score 1):

In *C++11* in-class initializers became a possiblity through the use of a *brace-or-equal-initializer*:

```
struct A {
  A () { }
  A (int) : s2 ("stackoverflow") { }

  std::string s1 = "hello world";
  std::string s2 { "hello world" };
};
```

The above states that `s1` and `s2` will be initialized using the specified initializer, **unless** they are initialized in the *mem-initializer* of the called constructor.

> <sup>**Note**: If *A*  is initialized using `A(int)`, *s1* will be initialized with `"hello world"` and *s2* with `"stackoverflow"`; if the default constructor is called both *s1* and *s2* will use their in-class initializer.</sup>

---

Prior to *C++11* you had to use the *mem-initializer list* if you didn't want the member to be implicitly *default-constructed* prior to some assignment (in the body of the ctor).

```
struct A {
  A () {
    s1 = std::string ("hello world"); // copy-assignment
  }

  std::string s1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize them in the initialization list, then all the objects are *default initialized* (of course a default constructor needs to exist).

Then the syntax for assigning another value to them is:

```
obj = Object(params...);
```

for any class type `Object`. Where `obj` is a member object of the said class.

Comment: Does this make use of the copy constructor?

Comment: @Ben No. Copy assignment.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 added support for *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax for class members.  The *brace-or-equal-initializer* is used in any constructor that doesn't provide a specific initialization for that variable, including a compiler-generated default constructor (but not copy and move constructors).

The *brace-and-equal-initializer* will not be able to refer to a constructor parameter, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if the grammatical name clearly identifies that feature.. I had to think for a second what you're talking about (aka NSDMI)